# Stop AdMob Ads on Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, admob, ads

How can I make an AdMob AdView quit loading ads?  I'd love to kill their threads and allow all the garbage the view creates to be taken out.  We change views often in an application without opening new Activities and as far as I can tell there isn't a way scrap the garbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, the best answer is to make new activities when there will be a new view or to only switch out the parts of the layout that need to be updated.

Serving AdMob ads through Mobclix generates less garbage and allows mediation with other advertising providers.